# Is $*:U(R)\times R^+\longrightarrow R^+,\ (g,a)\mapsto g*a:=g\cdot a$ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

Let $R=(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring with $1_R$. We will write $U(R)=(U(R),\cdot)$ the multiplicative group of units of this ring and $R^+=(R,+)$ the additive group of this ring. The group $U(R)$ **acts** in the group $R^+$, if we define a group action
$$*:U(R)\times R^+\longrightarrow R^+,\ (g,a)\mapsto g*a:=g\cdot a.$$
Then, we know that the function
$$\phi: U(R)\longrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(R^+),\ g\mapsto \phi(g):=\phi_g $$
is a group homomorphism. We can show that $\ker {\phi}=\{1_G\}$, so $\phi$ is injective and we have monomorphism.

**My question:** Is $\phi $ surjective?

Lets take an element $\psi \in \mathrm{Aut}(R^+)$. We want to find an element $g\in U(R)$ such that $\phi(g)=\psi$. Then $\phi _g=\psi \iff \phi_g(r)=\psi(r),\ \forall r\in R^+ \iff g\cdot r=\psi (r), \forall r\in R^+$.

But how can we solve the last equation, to find $g$? Any ideas please?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. What are it’s units and how do the corresponding automorphisms look like? Now look at the automorphism interchanging $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Let $Z$ be a ring with "few" units, which is a subring of a ring/field $C$ with "many" units. For instance $Z=\mathbb Z$ and $C=\mathbb C$. Consider inside the ring $C[X]$ the subring $R$ of polynomials with free coefficient in $Z$. (It is a $Z$-algebra.) Then $U(R)$ "is" $Z$, but each map $X\to cX$, $c$ unit in $R$  induces an automorphism of the abelian group obtained from $R$ by applying the forgetful functor.

Comment: @MaikPickl Thank you for your comment. We know that  $U(\Bbb{Z}[x,y])=U(\Bbb{Z})=\{+1.-1\}$ So, for our homomorphism 
$$\phi : \{+1,-1\} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}[x,y]^+),\\
1\mapsto \mathrm{Id}_{\Bbb{Z}[x,y]} ,\\
-1\mapsto \mathrm{-Id}_{\Bbb{Z}[x,y]}.$$
And what do we conclude from this?

Comment: @Chris It was meant to show you that $\phi$ can’t be surjective.

Comment: @MaikPickl Ok, but I can not understand why we conclude that $\phi: \{+1,-1\}\longrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}[x,y]^+)$ is not surjective. Could you please explain? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Chris Because there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ that isn’t in the image of $\phi$. Namely the automorphism that just exchanges $x$ and $y$. It leaves $\mathbb{Z}$ fixed and is therefore not $-Id$ but it’s also not $Id$ since it interchanges $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @MaikPickl So, we have the authomorphism of $\Bbb{Z}[x,y]$,
$$\alpha:\Bbb{Z}[x,y]\longrightarrow \Bbb{Z}[x,y],\\
f(x,y)\mapsto \alpha (f(x,y)):= f(y,x).$$
And that means, for the element $\alpha \in \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}[x,y])$ there is not an element in $\{\pm 1\}$. Right?

Comment: @Chris Exactly!

Comment: @MaikPickl It's clear now. Thank you very much for all your comments.